# Is RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges available in WPF?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying out Entity Framework Code First. I can't seem to find the assembly/namespace to use for `RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` in WPF 4.0. Is this an ASP.NET-only feature? If not, what assembly should I reference?

**Here's my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Windows;
using CodeFirstTester.Models;

namespace CodeFirstTester
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            // this fails:
            Database.SetInitializer(new RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NerdDinners>());

            // The type or namespace name 'RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges'
            // could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
            // an assembly reference?)                

            using (var nerdDinners = new NerdDinners())
            {
                var dinner = new Dinner()
                {
                    Title = "Party at Scott's House",
                    EventDate = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2010"),
                    Address = "Building 40",
                    HostedBy = "scottgu@microsoft.com"
                };
                nerdDinners.Dinners.Add(dinner);
                nerdDinners.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find any MSDN documentation about that class. Are you sure, it made it into RTM?

Comment: I found this: http://www.scottleckie.com/2011/03/rc-of-entity-framework-4-1-including-ef-code-first-is-released/. It says, that this strategy is now called `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, but I didn't find anything about that on MSDN either... strange

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696142%28v=VS.103%29.aspx There are also the three available implementations of `IDatabaseInitializer` listed, including `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The initializer is called `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. It can be found in EntityFramework.dll (EF 4.1) in `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav! I guess they renamed the strategy when they went from CTP to RC.